# Where can I ask for "Google courses for Android Professionals"

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am not sure on which site I can ask a question about education for professionals? This is the question I wanted to post but I did not find any site where the question would not be off topic.

> I am an Android Professional (>5 years) and I'm looking for some
>   courses, to learn new stuff. I heard about Udacity, but it seems that
>   those courses are for beginners only. Even some of their advances
>   topics seems to be quiet basic out of my view.
>
> It looks like the [Nanodegree](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-developer-nanodegree-by-google--nd801?v=ad1) for beginners, but who is the target
>   group of the [Associate Android Developer Exam](https://www.udacity.com/google-certifications)?
>
> Could this be something for a professional?
>
> If both courses are for beginners is there something for
>   professionals?

Comment: If there's an Android-specific chat room connected to [so], you might ask in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nowhere.

Such question would always end in a recommendation to do X or Y, which is generally off-topic on any site in the network. Such questions tend to attract spam or are outdated in just a short amount of time.

Comment: My question is basically who is the target group which is nothing to discuss. Just the last sentence opens discussions which I should avoid.

Comment: Then it will boil down to experience and opinions, which will make it primarily opinion based.

Comment: I see, I guess you are right.